# Backbone Model save - this.model.get('id') undefined

Tags: backbone.js

Using this:

```
        this.model.save(null, {
            success: function(model) {
                app.router.navigate('items/' + model.get('id'));
                this.render();
            }
        });
```

Has anyone got any ideas why model.get('id') would be undefined, yet model.id has the new id from the server?

Comment: Have you changed the `idAttribute` in the model? If it was set to something other than `id` it would explain what you see.

Comment: Can you give more details as to what attribute did you set to the model before save. What is the server response. Is the server response valid according to the model's validate methode ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .get method on a Backbone model will retrieve an 'attribute' (ie. property) from the 'attributes' property (object) of the model. It will not retrieve properties on the model that are not part of those attributes - model.id is a property on the model itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `success` callback takes three arguments - `(model, response, options)`.

Try `response.id` or `console.log` out response.